# Change value of a observable that's already been used - deferred promise?

Tags: knockout.js, promise, durandal

My Durandel/knockout app uses a config file to set values such as the host url. I want to be able to have an option to change this host url at login. I have added the correct KO to my login viewmodel and login view to change the host url. Problem is this does not actually change the host on login submission. Reason for this is that the host url is read and used before we get to the login.

Here is the journey of the app at the moment. Changing the observable value at login.js/login does not go back and change the value at pathservice.js
I need pathservice.js to look at login.js for the value however login.js will not load without pathservice and pathservice can't see the value in login.js as that view does not exist yet.

Configvalues > pathservices.js > some other routes > login.js

Any suggestions? Here is the watered down version of the code mentioned in running order.

**ConfigValues.js -**

```
define(
    function(){
        return {
            dateTimeFormat: "ddd Do MMM YYYY, HH:mm",
            logHttpRequests: true,
            logHttpResponses: true,
            offlineLoginOnly: false,
            requestTimeout: 120000,
            Host: "http://myurl.com",
            Path: "services/v1-0",
            ssoEnabled: true,
            useTestPDF: false,
            versionNumber: ''
        };
    }
);
```

**pathservices.js -**

```
define(
    [
        'uri',
        'configValues'
    ],
    function(
        uri,
        config
        ){

        // this comes before I can change the observable
        var Root = config.Host;


                return {

                //various returns that build up the app
        };
    }
);
```

**login.js -**

```
define([
    'configValues',
    'lodash',
    'viewmodels/shell',
    'knockout',
    'plugins/router',
    'durandal/app',
    'jquery',
    'services/pathService',
], function (
    config,
    _,
    shell,
    ko,
    router,
    app,
    $,
    pathService,
) {


    //below added in to observe and change view input but its too late
    var hostUrlChange = ko.observable();
    hostUrlChange(config.Host);

        return {
        activate: function() {
            shell.showNav(true);
        },

        hostUrlChange: hostUrlChange,
    };
});
```

**login.html -**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: hostUrlChange, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Comment: so, is `hostUrl`'s value deciding for the login page, or is it that you just need to update it after the login was done??

Comment: I need to be able to update the host url at the login screen... but the config value has already been passed before we get there, therefore when I change the observable its too late.

Comment: and where is this value coming from? I mean, is user providing this value at login? Pardon me if my question sounds vague :)

Comment: So the value is initially set in 'configvalues.js' the default value. At login I need to give the user an option to change this value. However, the default value has already been used to build various things for the app before login even appears.

Comment: I dont know if I am still able to get what you are trying to say, but If you are trying to get values from the user, then that has to be at some point after the UI has been rendered...which is too late because everything would be built by that time...however, if you want some other values to change to the user provided value, you can give `jquery callbacks` a try..

Comment: thanks for your help @gkb